# Spring Boot - Jpa Repository

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I have encountered this below piece of code in a sample project. I couldn't understand how the findItemsById method works without defining it properly. This method was declared in the ItemsRepository interface which extends JpaRepositiry.

```
public interface ItemsRepo extends JpaRepository<Items,Long> {
Optional<Items> findItemsById(Long id);
}
```

And in the service class, it is defined like given below.

```
public Items findItemsById(Long id) throws Throwable {
    return itemsRepo.findItemsById(id).orElseThrow(()-> new UserNotFoundException("items by id "+id+" not found"));
}
```

How it is working without actual definition for findItemsById. Does declaring it as optional have any relation with this?

Comment: spring has an engine that will scan anything that extends `JpaRepository` and provide you with an actual class.

Comment: @Eugene. Thanks for your answer. I couldn't understand " provide you with an actual class". Can you bit elaborate on that? Thanks Again

Comment: instead of an _interface_ `ItemsRepo`, at runtime, you will have an actual _class_, where those methods will be implemented.

Answer (score 1):

Spring Data repository query derivation mechanism to express the predicate is the feature that allows this. Basically, the query is derived by "parsing" the method name. There are rules (you must use your entities attributes' names) and keywords (`find`, `by`, `count`, etc...) for this. You can check additional information at:

- https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.query-creation
- https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repository-query-keywords
- https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-derived-queries

Answer (score 0):

You better Ctrl click on `JpaRepository<Items,Long>` Interface and follow it's method and it's parent method

There you will see all methods and you can understand those methods

For details understanding you can follow spring docs